# How far will a water hose shoot?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was thinking about aiming with a water hose for my pet project. Let's say I know the water pressure, height and angle from the ground and the diameter of the nozzle. How important is the roughness of the exit? If it has a considerable effect how would I measure it? How far will it shoot? Can I reasonably account for the change in direction caused by wind if I know it's direction and speed?(I think this might be too complex to calculate without simulations) I only had two semesters of physics at college and when I tried to solve it myself I couldn't.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the roughness of the exit"? The surface roughness of the nozzle?

Comment: He means the internal roughness of the nozzle.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: The water is landing at a different level than the nozzle that it exited from?  Also, are the water droplets considered to be projectiles or do you want to include air resistance in the problem?

Comment: The water is landing at a different level than the nozzle, if the air resistance contributes considerably then yes it should be included, and I don't know if water droplets can be considered projectiles.